# Error in node_crypto.cc when building node.js with nvm

Tags: build

The error message is the following (tried with multiple versions of node v0.4.1, v0.4.7, etc):

```
../src/node_crypto.cc:101:29: error: ‘SSLv2_method’ was not declared in this scope
../src/node_crypto.cc:103:36: error: ‘SSLv2_server_method’ was not declared in this scope
../src/node_crypto.cc:105:36: error: ‘SSLv2_client_method’ was not declared in this scope
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/gustavo/.nvm/src/node-v0.4.7/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx node_crypto.cc -> node_crypto_4.o}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oneiric and later releases openssl is built with sslv2 disabled due to known security flaws with that version of the protocol.

Since node v0.4.9 the configure script can detect if sslv2 is enabled or not and take the correct action ([commit f23c45f7f461](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/f23c45f7f46143c225696b57422234d746698b73)).

The other option is to disable ssl when you build node.